# Create additional columns based on other column values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have following data in a PostgreSQL table:

```
trial   start_date  end_date            
1       20_12_2001  20_01_2005
```

The expected output is below:

```
trial   start_date  end_date    Date[(start_end_date)]  marker_start_end
1       20_12_2001  20_01_2005  20_12_2001              start
1       20_12_2001  20_01_2005  20_01_2005              end
```

Is there a way to calculate the additional two columns (Date[(start_end_date)], marker_start_end) without join, but a CASE expression

Comment: No, there is no way to do that, unless in combination with a `UNION`. A `CASE` statement will allow more complex conditions to produce columns for a row but it will not produce additional rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lateral join to turn two columns into two rows:

```
select *
from the_table t
   cross join lateral (
     values (t.start_date, 'start'), (t.end_date, 'end')
   ) as x(start_end_date, marker);
```

The `UNION ALL` solution might be faster though.

Comment: Nice solution. Union all is fastest, but where condition must be repeated twice, so not so friendly

Comment: The OP asked for a solution with a `CASE` statement, specifically not a JOIN

Comment: But to multiply rows it can be join with optional case or union without need of case. Sounds like mission impossible :)

Comment: Sounds like a SQL course assignment to me!

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL`

```
select trial, start_date, end_date, start_date as date, 'start' marker_start_end from table1
union all
select trial, start_date, end_date, end_date as date, 'end' marker_start_end from table1
```

`UNNEST` with `CASE`

```
select trial, start_date, end_date, 
case when a.num = 1 then start_date else end_date end date, 
case when a.num = 1 then 'start' else 'end' end marker_start_end from
(
select trial, start_date, end_date, 
unnest(array[1,2]) num from table1
) a
```

Hidden `JOIN` (but still join)

```
select 
  trial, 
  start_date, 
  end_date, 
  case when a.num = 1 then start_date else end_date end date, 
  marker_start_end 
from table1, (values(1,'start'),(2, 'end')) a(num,marker_start_end)
```

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=27b1552ab93ff85f220ab97eccbe305f)